# filling a string made by new in a function

Tags: c++, string, function, pointers, new-operator

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void generCad(int n, char* cad){

int longi = 1, lastchar, m = n; // calculating lenght of binary string
char actual;
do{
    longi++;
    n /= 2;
}while(n/2 != 0);
cad = new char[longi];
lastchar = longi - 1;
do{
    actual = m % 2;
    cad[lastchar] = actual;
    m /= 2;
    lastchar--;
}while(m/2 != 0);
cout << "Cadena = " << cad;
```

}

Hi! I'm having a problem here because I need a function that creates a binary string for a number n. I think the process is "good" but cout doesn't print anything, I don't know how to fill the string I've created using the new operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should look like this:

```
void generCad(int n, char** cad)
{
    int m = n, c = 1;

    while (m >>= 1) // this divides the m by 2, but by shifting which is faster
        c++; // here you counts the bits
    *cad = new char[c + 1];
    (*cad)[c] = 0; // here you end the string by 0 character

    while (n)
    {
        (*cad)[--c] = n % 2 + '0';
        n /= 2;
    }
            cout << "Cadena = " << *cad;
}
```

Note that cad is now char ** and not char *. If it is just char * then you do not get the pointer as you expect outside the function. If you do not need the string outside this function, then it may be passed as char *, but then do not forget to delete the cad before you leave the function (good habit ;-))

EDIT:

This code will probably be more readable and do the same:

```
char * toBin(int n)
{
    int m = n, c = 1;

    while (m >>= 1) // this divides the m by 2, but by shifting which is faster
        c++; // here you counts the bits
    char *cad = new char[c + 1];
    cad[c] = 0; // here you end the string by 0 character

    while (n)
    {
        cad[--c] = n % 2 + '0';
        n /= 2;
    }
    cout << "Cadena = " << cad;
    return cad;
}

int main()
{
    char *buff;
    buff = toBin(16);

    delete [] buff;

    return 1;

}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you but I dont understand your code, I've just want a function that receives a pointer to char and returns the pointer to a string witch is the binary string of the value of n. (Modificating the pointer, and the string)

Comment: The output of your code is in hexadecimal! :S, calling with `generCad(n,&cadena);`

Comment: Say to me your real name because you are god, Jehova maybe?? sorry for my english and thank u!!!!! ;)

Answer (score 0):

`actual` contains *the numbers* `0` and `1`, not *the characters* `'0'` and `'1'`. To convert, use:

```
cad[lastchar] = actual + '0';
```

Also, since you're using `cad` as a C string, you need to allocate an extra character and add a NUL terminator.

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried and doesn't work, I've changed this:                                        `    cad = new char[longi+1];
        ultimocar = longi - 1;
        cad[longi] = '\0';`

Answer (score 0):

```
actual = m % 2;
```

should be:

```
actual = m % 2 + '0';
```